# Using flags for custom enum types

Tags: go

I have code like this:

```
type CarType int

const (
    sedan CarType = iota
    coupe
    suv
    convertible
    sports
    mini
    pickup
    hachback
)

func (c CarType) String() string {
    cartypes := [...]string{
        Sedan,
        Coupe,
        SUV,
        Convertible,
        Sports,
        Mini,
        Pickup,
        Hatchback,
    }

    return cartypes[c]
}
```

How do i accept CarType as a flag input from a user? Can a custom flag type be created for it or should i just accept an int input and convert it (seeems ugly) or accept a string (better, but will need to be converted). Are there any go idioms for this?

Comment: Implement the `pflag.Value` interface. Consider using the `enumer` package to codegen most of the implementation details https://github.com/alvaroloes/enumer. Yet it depends on which libraries you already use...

Answer (score -2):

You can issue a list and select form on the html's select form if you can

If not, I don't think there's no good way to do anything but your two methods

Comment: Its a cli tool, not html.